Extra energy by applying torque?
Consider two blocks of same mass m lying horizontally. A bullet is fired at first block at its center of mass vertically upwards. It sticks inside the block and the block goes up to a height of $y$ units and falls due to gravitational force of earth. Then another bullet of same mass is fired from the same gun at its corner. The bullet stick at the block and the block undergoes both translational and rotational motion. It also goes vertically up till exactly $y$ units while rotating with some angular velocity about its center of mass. There is no air friction or any other type of friction in both cases. Now we know that both the bullets when released from gun will have same kinetic energy. This energy will be used to lift the blocks from horizontal surface and give them kinetic energy. Hence both the blocks must have same kinetic energy. But the kinetic energy of the first block is simply $ \frac 12 mv^2$ where $v$ is its initial velocity and the kinetic energy of second block is $ \frac 12 mv_2^2 + \frac 12 I_{com} \omega^2 $ where $v_2$ and $\omega $ are its inital velocity and angular velocity respectively. $v$ and $v_2$ must be equal due to conservation of linear momentum. Now we can clearly see that the second block has more kinetic energy . From where did this energy come? Consider this simulation from oPhysics .

In both cases the collisions are inelastic (as the bullet stops inside the block), so some of the initial kinetic energy is converted to heat due to friction between the block and the bullet. The amount is different  between the two cases.
The bullet is slowed less by the collision in the second case, as the side of the block which is hit will be moving more quickly than the other side, even though the centre of mass of the block/bullet system moves at the same speed in both cases. This means less energy is converted to heat in the second case.
